# Is it possible to transfer VCS settings in Omnis Studio from one version to another?

Tags: omnis-studio-10, omnis-studio-8

Is there an easy way to transfer the VCS login session/settings from one version of Omnis to another?

Where is the VCS connection information stored in an Omnis Studio Developer installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VCS session info, along with all SQL session information is stored in the local database sql.df1

This can be found in the studio folder, either for windows within the app data folder, or for mac, in the application support folders.

This is also the folder where config files are stored, like config.json or appearance.json which you maybe able to copy over directly to new releases, but you may need to check out specific detail changes.